# webrtc build error with vs2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webrtc, ninja

After "gn gen out/Default - -ide=vs2015" I try to debug webrtc with vs2015,it failed and show information below:

```
1>  ninja: Entering directory `../../../../out/Default/'
1>  [1/465] LINK genperf.exe genperf.exe.pdb
1>  FAILED: genperf.exe genperf.exe.pdb
1>  D:/depot_tools/win_tools-2_7_6_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/toolchain/win/tool_wrapper.py link-wrapper environment.x64 False link.exe  /OUT:./genperf.exe /PDB:./genperf.exe.pdb @./genperf.exe.rsp
1>  Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.00.24210.0
1>
1>  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
1>
1>
1>
1>  obj/third_party/yasm/genperf/genperf.obj
1>
1>  obj/third_party/yasm/genperf/perfect.obj
1>
1>  obj/third_party/yasm/yasm_utils.lib advapi32.lib comdlg32.lib dbghelp.lib delayimp.lib dnsapi.lib gdi32.lib kernel32.lib msimg32.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib psapi.lib shell32.lib shlwapi.lib user32.lib usp10.lib uuid.lib version.lib wininet.lib winmm.lib winspool.lib ws2_32.lib /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /fastfail /FIXED:NO /ignore:4199 /ignore:4221 /NXCOMPAT /DYNAMICBASE:NO /INCREMENTAL /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE,5.02 /WX /manifest:embed /manifestuac:no /manifestinput:../../build/win/as_invoker.manifest /manifestinput:../../build/win/common_controls.manifest /manifestinput:../../build/win/compatibility.manifest /LIBPATH:../../third_party/llvm-build/Release+Asserts/lib/clang/6.0.0/lib/windows "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/winv6.3/um/x64" "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/lib/amd64" "/LIBPATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/lib/amd64"
1>
1>
1>
1>../../build/win/as_invoker.manifest : manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "requestedPrivileges" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3".
1>
1>
1>
1>
1>../../build/win/compatibility.manifest : manifest authoring warning 81010002: Unrecognized Element "compatibility" in namespace "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1".
1>
1>
1>EXEC : fatal error RC1106: invalid option: -ologo
1>
1>
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1327: 运行 rc.exe 期间出错
1>
1>  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
1>X:\opensource\webrtc20171120\src\out\Default\obj\api\api.vcxproj(56,5): error MSB3073: 命令“call ninja.exe -C ../../../../out/Default/  obj/api/api.stamp”
```

Has anyone come across the problem